# How to add RealmObject to RealmList?

Tags: realm

I am trying to add SongRealm to SongListRealm like this:

```
public void insertSongToListWithKey(final int key, Song song){
    final SongRealm songRealm = mapper.toRealm(song);
    realm.beginTransaction();

    SongListRealm songListRealm = realm.where(SongListRealm.class).equalTo("key", key).findFirst();
    if(songListRealm!=null){
        songListRealm.getSongList().add(songRealm);
        realm.insertOrUpdate(songListRealm);
    }

    realm.commitTransaction();
}
```

Before:

> SongList named "A" {song named "1", song named "2"}
>
> SongList named "B" {song named "14"}

After:

> SongList named "A" {song named "4", song named "4"}
>
> SongList named "B" {song named "4", song named "4"}

What am I doing wrong? Have a nice evening. Thanks you in advance.

**EDIT**

I'm adding more code :)

SongListMapper (class to change SongListRealm on SongList) method:

```
public SongList fromRealm(SongListRealm songListRealm){
    SongList songList = new SongList();
    ArrayList<Song> songArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    RealmList<SongRealm> realmSongList = songListRealm.getSongList();
    for(SongRealm songRealm: realmSongList){
        songArrayList.add(songMapper.fromRealm(songRealm));
    }
    songList.setSongList(songArrayList);
    songList.setTitle(songListRealm.getName());
    songList.setKey(songListRealm.getKey());
    return songList;
}
```

SongMapper (class to change SongRealm on Song and vice versa):

```
public Song fromRealm(SongRealm songRealm){
    Song song = new Song();
    song.setArtist(songRealm.getArtist());
    song.setId(songRealm.getId());
    song.setPath(songRealm.getPath());
    song.setTitle(songRealm.getTitle());
    return song;
}
```

getAllTheSongLists() method:

```
public ArrayList<SongList> getAllTheSongLists() {
    ArrayList<SongList> songs = new ArrayList<>();
    SongListMapper mapper = new SongListMapper();
    RealmResults<SongListRealm> all = realm.where(SongListRealm.class).findAll().sort("key");
    for (SongListRealm songRealm : all) {
        if(songRealm.getKey()==idLastSongListValue)
            continue;
        songs.add(mapper.fromRealm(songRealm));
    }
    return songs;
}
```

I'm saving last used SongList with key in idLastSongListValue variable - so it isn't SongList created by user and i don't want to display it for user.

**[Solved]**

I had to create new object with new Primary Key and set variables of Song object to created SongRealm object and copy method from EpicPandaForce. Hope it will help you.

```
public void insertSongToListWithKey(final int key, final Song song){
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm r) {
            SongRealm songRealmNew = createSongRealm(song);
            SongListRealm songListRealm = realm.where(SongListRealm.class).equalTo("key", key).findFirst();
            if (songListRealm != null) {
                SongRealm savedSongRealm = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(songRealmNew);
                RealmList<SongRealm> songs = songListRealm.getSongList();
                if(!songs.contains(savedSongRealm)) {
                    songs.add(savedSongRealm);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

private SongRealm createSongRealm(Song song){
    SongRealm songRealmNew = realm.createObject(SongRealm.class, generateIdForSong());
    songRealmNew.setId(song.getId());
    songRealmNew.setTitle(song.getTitle());
    songRealmNew.setPath(song.getPath());
    songRealmNew.setArtist(song.getArtist());
    return songRealmNew;
}

 private int generateIdForSong() {
    if(realm.where(SongRealm.class).max("key")==null)
        return 0;
    return realm.where(SongRealm.class).max("key").intValue() + 1;
 }
```

Comment: Please don't edit the solution into your question or add stuff like "Solved" to your title. Accepting the answer is enough.

Comment: The solution should be a separate answer - you can add an answer to your own question if you figured it out after you posted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it should be like this:

```
public void insertSongToListWithKey(final int key, Song song){
    final SongRealm songRealm = mapper.toRealm(song);
    realm.executeTransaction((r) -> {
        SongListRealm songListRealm = realm.where(SongListRealm.class).equalTo("key", key).findFirst();
        if(songListRealm != null) {
            SongRealm savedSongRealm = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(songRealm);
            RealmList<SongRealm> songs = songListRealm.getSongList();
            if(!songs.contains(savedSongRealm)) {
                songs.add(savedSongRealm);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What classes would you to see?

Comment: I don't know. The one that overwrites both of your song lists.

Comment: I added some code. If you want to see more please write. The result of your method is that i can't add more than one song to SongList. Before adding Playlist named '1' {Song named '1'},  Playlist named '5' {Song named '3'}    After adding song named '6' to playlist named '1': Playlist named '1' {Song named '6', Playlist named '5' {Song named '6'}. Why program adding it to all SongLists?

Comment: if `key` is a `String` then it should be compared with `equals` instead of `==`.

Comment: Key its int variable

Comment: The exception was in mapping. I had to create object with primary key first. Thanks for help :)